# Implement Canny detector's hysteresis thresholding in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, canny-operator

I'm recently learning [Canny edge detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector), and did a small implementation from scratch of the algorithm as a hobby.

Honestly, I did not expect it to be super fast or ever come close to the speed of famous implementation such as one in OpenCV, but I do want my implementation to be fast enough (about 3 or 4 times as OpenCV's implementation).

After overcoming some problems along the way, I found myself stuck at the hysteresis thresholding step, where I had no idea how to improve its speed, my code is as follows:

```
class fnc_class:
    def __init__(self, high_im=None):
        self.pos = [0, 0]
        self.high_im = high_im
        self.shape = high_im.shape

    def update_coordinate(self):
        if (self.pos == [self.shape[0],self.shape[1]]):
            self.pos = [0,0]
        for axis in (1, 0):
            if self.pos[axis] < self.shape[axis] - 1:
                self.pos[axis] += 1
                break
            else:
                self.pos[axis] = 0

    def hysteresis_threshold(self, possible_correct):
        if (possible_correct[4] > 0.5):
            possible_correct = possible_correct.reshape(3, 3)

            if (self.high_im[(self.pos[0]-1):(self.pos[0]+2),(self.pos[1]-1):(self.pos[1]+2)].sum() > 0.5):
                self.update_coordinate()
                return possible_correct[1, 1]
        
        self.update_coordinate()
        return 0

# arr : gradient magnitudes
def hysteresis_threshold(arr, high, low):
    high_im = arr*(arr >= high)
    low_im = arr*(arr >= low)

    possible_correct = low_im - high_im
    possible_correct[possible_correct < 0] = 0

    func = fnc_class(high_im=high_im)
    possible = 0

    for i in range(0,50):
        possible = scipy.ndimage.generic_filter(possible_correct, func.hysteresis_threshold, size=(3,3))
        func.high_im = possible + high_im


    hysteresis = possible + high_im
    return hysteresis
```

This is the part that constitute most of the computing time of my implementation.

The time taken using `time.time()` function:

```
My time: 5.349750995635986
OpenCV time: 0.0004572868347167969
```

I knew that `for i in range(0,50)` to repeatedly "expand" the `high_im` seemed like a stupid idea, which was basically a brute-force approach, but I don't know how to "expand" the high-thresholded edges without looping like that.

How can I possibly use any other approach to improve the speed? I want to minimize the usage of helper libraries as much as possible, except essential library such as Scipy or Numpy.

Comment: Unfortunately it does require looping, unless you use an existing function in a library (where the loops are written in a compiled language). Your implementation is very weird though. `high_im` and `low_im` should be binary images, not grayscale (i.e. you discard the original gray values after the two thresholds). Now you iteratively dilate the `high_im` within the areas marked by `low_im`, until no further change is possible. 50 steps might be too many, or not enough, you can't pick a maximum number of steps like that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I coded it based on what I read in theory books. Sometimes they are not very clear about such details.